# HTML Table Body Positioning and Scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table, padding

As pictured in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zejGZ/3/), I have a three tables on a page.  I want to be able to scroll the body of "Leaderboard" and "Queue," leaving the caption and table header alone.  Preferably without absolute positioning.

<strike>Somewhat related, I also need the table (not including the `caption` to have a little bit of padding on the sides (but not between individual cells).</strike>

Answer (score 2):

Add `overflow: scroll;` to your divs and include a `height`. If you only want to scroll in one direction, instead you could do `overflow-x` for horizontal scrolling and `overflow-y` for vertical scrolling. For detecting if the div even needs to be scrollable, use `overflow: auto;`.

Comment: Yes, but _what_ height?  If I want this to be dynamic, then I can't just give it a height.

Comment: @CMC: You don't have to set a height, but you won't get the scroll, it'll just keep stretching the page. Maybe you want to set a max-height?

Comment: You can specify any height you desire and the div would be the same height, but the content of the div is dynamic. The content is what causes the need for scrolling, the _content_ is dynamic.

Comment: @Musafa The content inside is dynamic, but so is the height of the container/table.  That means I can't set a height for either.

Comment: @CMC so if you want the container to be the same height of the content, what are you trying to scroll?

Comment: You don't understand.  I don't want the container to be the same size as the content.  If you look at the Fiddle, the container is sized based on the window size (as you increase window height, the contained height increases).  The content, on the other hand, is created dynamically through Javascript.  The height of the content and the container are independent, but both dynamic.

Comment: you are unclear on what exactly you are trying to scroll. if you want the "On Deck" div to stop expanding with content at a certain point, you need to set a `max-height` value and set `overflow: auto` in the css.

Comment: My apologies.  I clarified the question.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: auto;` to the surrounding DIVs you want to scroll. You may want to set explicit heights, depending on your layout — you don't have to but it won't scroll if you don't. You could try setting a `max-height` if you want it to stretch only to a point. If you only want it to scroll vertically, some browsers support [`overflow-y: auto`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp), but not all.

Since the `<caption>` is in the table, you can't set the padding or margin on the table. You can either:

- Take the caption out of the table and make it a simple header like `h2`, then adding a margin to the table, or
- You can set padding-left on the left table cells/column and padding-right on the other side. Not real clean, but lets you keep the `<caption>` semantic if you want.